# Change placeholder value depending on locale - angularJS

Tags: angularjs, localization

Does angular localization provide this:
Can the placeholder value change depending on the locale?
I have an input control with `placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"`. It should change to `placeholder="TT/MM/JJJJ"` for German. Should we write a filter for this? or Angular locale provides it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to switch between german and the rest of the world, you can have something specific in your controller:

```
<input placeholder="{{getLocalePlaceholder()}}">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getLocalPlaceholder = function() {
  if ($local.id === 'de-de') {
    return 'TT/MM/JJJJ';
  }
  return 'mm/dd/yyyy';
}
```

If you want to be more generic, I suggest you write a directive which uses [$locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$locale) and a list of [all known locals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).

```
app.directive('placeholderByLocale', ['$locale', function($locale) {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs)  {
      function getLocaleFormat() {
        switch ($locale.id) {
          case 'de-de':
            return 'TT/MM/JJJJ';
          default:
            return 'mm/dd/yyyy';
        }
      }

      attrs.$set('placeholder', getLocaleFormat());
    }
  }
}])
```

[See Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TbgfGIg0VdTvy4XggpEC?p=preview)

You may also consider using [Date.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), in combination with the real day's date. Most users will quickly and correctly infer the date format from the example.

Keep in mind that the locale of the browser is not always an indicator of the user's location.